# Github deploy keys allow me to clone multiple private repositories

Tags: git

I have two repositories A (private) and B (pubic). I added a deploy key only to a repo A (private). However, I was able to clone both repositories on my server using ssh. It came as a surprise to me because I though a deploy key allows accessing only a repo to which it is attached.

Deploy key definion according to GitHub:

> A deploy key is an SSH key that is stored on your server and grants
>   access to a **single** GitHub repository

So, why am I able to clone private and a public repositories using ssh if I created a deploy key only for the repo A?

Comment: Can you run `ssh -Tv git@github.com` using that key and update your question with a code block with the output?